Are there something like standard documents for 8.3 filename which explicitly mention about the folder names?
It should be that for 8.3 filename, the folder names should not have extension part as
the filenames do.
I just searched around and only found a Microsoft page for 8.3 filename.
It is quite tiny and doesn't mention the folder names.
Therefore it occurred to me that, are there some thing like standard documents that explicitly mentions about the folder names?

Microsoft used folders with extensions, why shouldn’t they be allowed?

Directories are just files with special content.  Why should their names have different rules?  That requires writing more code for less flexibility.

Does the self-link directory entry '.' have an extension or not?   ;-)

@dave yes they have. following the standard it has to be filled with spaces. At least with DOS adding a period to a directory name works fine :))

Directory entries on FAT use the same 8.3 name format that file entries do.  The only difference is that directories have a special bit (mask 0x10) set on their "attributes" byte.

@StephenKitt FAT subdirectories contain entries for dot and dotdot (the literal filename contents are one or two dots "." followed by 10 or 9 blanks). However, DOS file system drivers may or may not use these entries at all.

@dave, Wait, Are you saying that every directory in a FAT-12 or FAT-16 file system had a "." entry? And did they also have a ".."? I'm not sure where I would look to answer that question today, but I feel like I would remember it if it were true. I avoided UNIX for a lot of years, learning about other computer OSs with their own weird, hierarchical file systems. I distinctly remember, when I finally did come too UNIX, the whole "." and ".." thing blew my mind. "Why didn't any of the other OSs have anything like it? It was so simple. So obvious in hindsight."

I was talking about NTFS.  Nothing in the question is specific to FAT.  (Also, in NTFS on-disk structures, there is no 'extension' - like Unix file systems and unlike early FAT versions it's just a single name, maybe containing dots).

@Dave, OK, Yeah. The page to which the OP linked is documentation for modern Windows. I was trying to understand the question as if it were a "retrocomputing" question.

@Ohm'sLawman - in any case, it was a tongue-in-cheek comment.  If you consider '.' to merely separate the name and extension  (as FAT did) then there is no name and no extension in the '.' entry.  A fatuous claim for a file system such as NTFS, which does not treat the '.' as special.  I guess that joke fell flat!

Standard documents that explicitly mentions what about the folder names?

@Ohm'sLawman FAT12, FAT16, and FAT32 do generally have on-disk entries for dot and dotdot, in every subdirectory. They are usually the first two entries of the subdirectory. The root directory does not have such entries. However, the use of .. to navigate "up" in a directory hierarchy is probably handled by DOS internally without referencing the on-disk entries

TL;DR: ECMA-107
The 1995 ECMA-107 is the official international standard document describing the FAT file system in great detail and many words ... quite as one expects from a standard :))
It codifies best practice to handle a FAT-based disk system. Section 6.5 explains how path names are built and that sub-directories (your "folders") of course may have an extension part. This is further described in great detail in section 11 for all file directory entries in general and 11.6 for directory names in particular.


It should be that for 8.3 filename, the folder names should not have extension part as the filenames do.

Who says directories should not be able to use extensions to mark their type? It can be quite useful to name dirs according to their content, not to mention that some OS, like OPENVMS even mandated that directories are names with '.DIR' :))

I just searched around and only found a Microsoft page for 8.3 filename.

Beside various Microsoft originated/related documents, we should consider ECMA-107 as it's the official international standard.

It is quite tiny and doesn't mention the folder names.

Why should it? It only defines how 8.3 names are constructed. Those are used in directory entries independent of further attributes - like being a directory, hidden, system or volume label.
A file system handles those names all in the same way, stored in the same directory and processed the same way. They only diverge when the content is accessed, but not otherwise when handling directory entries.
Thus directories have the very same naming convention as any otehr file entry: 11 characters, usually displayed as 1..8 char, a dot and another 1..3 chars. After all, the 'extension is as arbitrary as the name part. The file system does not hold it to any meaning.

Therefore it occurred to me that, are there some thing like standard documents that explicitly mentions about the folder names?

Again, why? They use the same naming as any other directory entry, thus there is no need to have another convention. A dedicated document would only be needed if there were a difference in naming, wouldn't it?
I would not know of any other (micro) OS that handles directory names differently to other file names. No matter whether it's Apple ProDOS or Unix, names are names are names.
The only part that differentiates FAT file names from most other file systems is the way that the 11-character file name is handled if a period is present.

There may be no documentation for that specific thing you ask.
Each directory entry has reserved 8 characters for the file name and 3 characters for the extension.
It's the type of the entry that may matter, but it does not matter for files and directories.
For files and directories it works the same. You can create a file called "HELLO.TXT" or a directory called "HELLO.TXT". It's just the attributes of the entry that state if the entry is for a file or a directory.
If the entry attributes indicate that it is an entry for a disk label instead of for a file or a directory, the DIR command and the LABEL command show it as a single 11 character name without a dot.

The main use of the file extension is to indicate the type of the file content. Since a directory is treated specially by the operating system, and its internal "file content" is not accessible, there is no need to use an extension to indicate that it is a directory.
At the file system level, directories may have extensions as regular files do. No technical restriction prevents it. But there is no standard use of it.

OpenVMS uses “.DIR” as the extension on directory names.

@RonJohn Thanks for the information! That's really unique and interesting. I'm glad to know that.

DG RDOS had two character extensions and directories had an extension of ".DR" that would show in directory listings but you didn't have to type it when a directory name was expected.
